# MY sql sumif return double count

Tags: mysql

I Have four table department, team, expense, and earning.

Depart Table:

```
id  depart
```

Team Table:

```
id  name    depart_id
```

Expense Table:

```
id  team_id expense_type    amount  date
```

And Earning Table:

```
id  team_id earning_type earning_peace  date
```

I want to calculate depart vise total expense amount and total earning peaces. I use this query:

```
SELECT d.id, d.depart, 
SUM(if(`earning_type` = 1, earning_peace, 0)) as earning_peace1, 
SUM(if(`earning_type` = 2, earning_peace, 0)) as earning_peace2, 
SUM(if(`earning_type` = 3, earning_peace, 0)) as earning_peace3,
SUM(if(`earning_type` = 4, earning_peace, 0)) as earning_peace4,
SUM(if(`expense_type` = 1, amount, 0)) as `expense1`, 
SUM(if (`expense_type` = 2, amount, 0)) as expense2, 
SUM(if (`expense_type` = 3, amount, 0)) as expense3, 
SUM(if (`expense_type` = 4, amount, 0)) as expense4 
FROM depart d INNER JOIN team m ON d.id = m.depart_id 
LEFT JOIN earning e ON m.id = e.team_id
LEFT JOIN expense ex ON ex.team_id = m.id
GROUP BY d.id
```

But query return double amount of total earnig on some depart. What is the mistake in this query any help?

Comment: You're creating a multi-branch join tree with d->m->e and d->m->ex. this can lead to odd results like this.

Comment: @Marc B yes but what is the solution?

Comment: don't do multi-branch joins. do a `select * from ....` without the sums, and you'll see how crazy the results can look when you do multi-branch.

Comment: No sum if return like a pivot query and with * I can't get it.

Comment: then don't do pivot queries at the mysql level. it's far better to the pivoting in PHP as you're fetching the results.

Comment: Please stop using MySQL's `GROUP BY` extension. It is not ANSI standard and will end up hurting you in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the one trick it might be slow for huge data sets but proper indexes can give it a live ,make datasets for earnings and expenses separately then join both data-sets

```
SELECT * FROM 

(SELECT d.id AS did, d.depart, 
SUM( CASE WHEN `expense_type` = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END )  AS `expense1`,
SUM( CASE WHEN `expense_type` = 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END )  AS `expense2`,
SUM( CASE WHEN `expense_type` = 3 THEN amount ELSE 0 END )  AS `expense3`,
SUM( CASE WHEN `expense_type` = 4 THEN amount ELSE 0 END )  AS `expense4`
FROM depart d 
LEFT JOIN team m ON d.id = m.depart_id 
LEFT JOIN earning e ON m.id = e.team_id
GROUP BY d.id
) expensetable 

INNER JOIN
(
SELECT d.id AS did, d.depart, 
SUM( CASE WHEN `earning_type` = 1 THEN earning_peace ELSE 0 END )   AS earning_peace1,
SUM( CASE WHEN `earning_type` = 2 THEN earning_peace ELSE 0 END )   AS earning_peace2,
SUM( CASE WHEN `earning_type` = 3 THEN earning_peace ELSE 0 END )   AS earning_peace3,
SUM( CASE WHEN `earning_type` = 4 THEN earning_peace ELSE 0 END )   AS earning_peace4
FROM depart d 
LEFT JOIN team m ON d.id = m.depart_id 
LEFT JOIN expense ex ON ex.team_id = m.id
GROUP BY d.id
) earningtable  ON (expensetable.did = earningtable.did)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @MarcB comments you are creating a multi-branch join tree.  I think it would be better if you execute the aggregates separately and then combine the results:

```
SELECT
    d.id,
    d.depart,
    ea.earning_peace1,
    ea.earning_peace2,
    ea.earning_peace3,
    ea.earning_peace4,
    ex.expense1,
    ex.expense2,
    ex.expense3,
    ex.expense4
FROM
    depart d
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            t.depart_id,
            SUM(if(`earning_type` = 1, earning_peace, 0)) as earning_peace1, 
            SUM(if(`earning_type` = 2, earning_peace, 0)) as earning_peace2, 
            SUM(if(`earning_type` = 3, earning_peace, 0)) as earning_peace3,
            SUM(if(`earning_type` = 4, earning_peace, 0)) as earning_peace4
        FROM
            earning e
            INNER JOIN team t ON t.id = e.team_id
        GROUP BY t.depart_id
    ) ea ON ea.depart_id = d.id
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            t.depart_id,
            SUM(if(`expense_type` = 1, amount, 0)) as `expense1`, 
            SUM(if (`expense_type` = 2, amount, 0)) as expense2, 
            SUM(if (`expense_type` = 3, amount, 0)) as expense3, 
            SUM(if (`expense_type` = 4, amount, 0)) as expense4
        FROM
            expense x,
            INNER JOIN team t ON t.id = x.team_id
        GROUP BY t.depart_id
    ) ex ON ex.depart_id = d.id
```

Comment: depart column is varchar, and I am not getting currect result by this.